# Extract JSON attributes using Python and filter out some data

Tags: python, json, urllib2

JSON File: http://media1.clubpenguin.com/play/en/web_service/game_configs/paper_items.json
I'm using Python 2.

I am trying to extract all the 'paper_item_id' 's from the JSON file (specified above), using a loop and storing the 'paper_item_id' in a 'item_id' variable, so this variable will change each time the loop iterates to the 'paper_item_id', but also I want to have an if statement which checks if the 'paper_item_id' in the JSON file  'is_bait' is 'true' if it is true the the 'item_id' variable will not store the 'paper_item_id' which has an 'is_bait' of true and go on to the next one.

Step 1) Get JSON Data.
Step 2) Filter out 'paper_item_id' 's with the 'is_bait' to true.
Step 3) Run a loop which assigns a 'item_id' variable to the 'paper_item_id' received.
Step 4) The loop should run so all filtered 'paper_item_id' (item_id) has been passed to 'myFunction'

Sample English Like Code:

```
    foreach ('don't know what to have for the loop cond') {
        item_id = 'paper_item_id'
        if (item_id[is_bait]) == true  {
            code which will go to the end of the loop    
        }

        else 
        {
        myFunction(item_id)
        }
```

I know this has a Javascript kind-of syntax but I want it in python.

What I have now:

```
import json
import urllib2
url = 'http://media1.clubpenguin.com/play/en/web_service/game_configs/paper_items.json'
result = json.loads(url)
request = urllib2.Request(url)
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
json_obj = json.load(response)
```

What do I do know?

Comment: Your JSON contains an error. You will need to adjust for this at some point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used requests.get, and also checked for a valid HTTP response.

Here's my sample code:

```
import json
import requests

def myFunction(item):
    # do something here
    print item['paper_item_id']
    pass

json_obj = requests.get('http://media1.clubpenguin.com/play/en/web_service/game_configs/paper_items.json').json()


for item in json_obj:
    if 'is_bait' in item and item['is_bait'] == "1":
        # item['is_bait'] == "1", in case you ever get is_bait = "0" in your json response.
        print item['paper_item_id']
        continue
    else:
        myFunction(item)
```

Comment: i just want the paper_item_id number though

Comment: just edited code to show you how to get paper_item_id

Answer (score 1):

Here is the translation of what you give as a pseudo code:

```
import json
import urllib2
url = 'http://media1.clubpenguin.com/play/en/web_service/game_configs/paper_items.json'
result = json.loads(url)
request = urllib2.Request(url)
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
json_obj = json.load(response)
for item in json_obj:
    if "is_bait" in item and item['is_bait']:
        continue
    else:
        # do stuff
```

The continue can be skipped if you reverse the condition though.

Comment: Nope... let's not mislead OP

Comment: All I want is the paper item id's value, so i just want the numbers

Comment: The code will **not** work as posted. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

json.load will read your data into a list of dictionaries, as appropriate. After that, you can filter on whatever it is your heart desires using standard python object manipulation:

```
import json
import urllib2
url = 'http://media1.clubpenguin.com/play/en/web_service/game_configs/paper_items.json'
result = json.load(url)
request = urllib2.Request(url)
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
json_obj = json.load(response)
```

Your issue is that you're reading the URL object as a string and that's a non-starter. I fixed your code above and it now reads in the whole thing (snippet from output below:

```
 {u'cost': 0,
  u'is_bait': u'1',
  u'is_member': Terue,
  u'label': u"Stompin' Bob Fowhawk Hair",
  u'layer': 6000,
  u'paper_item_id': 1274,
  u'prompt': u"Stompin' Bob Fowhawk Hair",
  u'type': 2},
 {u'cost': 0,
  u'is_bait': u'1',
  u'is_member': True,
  u'label': u'G Billy Hair and Bandana',
  u'layer': 6000,
  u'paper_item_id': 1275,
  u'prompt': u'G Billy Hair and Bandana',
  u'type': 2},
  ... continues for a long time...
```

Comment: You can also convert the JSON into the correct format by doing `str_json = request.read().decode('utf-8')` and loading this instead.

Comment: while reading, can you filter out objects using object_hook in json.load method?